# unidirectional oneToMany relation with java persistence

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a class `TimeTable` that contains a set of objects of type `Year`.
A `Year` does not have any referene to any `TimeTable`.

On my database the relation is the other way 'round:
In the `YEARS` table is a foreign key `TIME_TABLE_ID`.

I'd now like to add my persistence annotations to those classes, but I can't find out the exact syntax for pure JPA (only for Hibernate which I don't want to use at the moment).

I think it could be sth like this:

```
class TimeTable{
....
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "YEARS", 
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TIME_TABLE_ID"), 
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="ID" ???))  // #### here ####
private Set<Year> years;
...
}
```

.. but I can't find out what this inverseJoinColumn is :(
Is it the name of the `ID` of an entry in the `TIMETABLE` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse join column is optional, I would recommend removing it, since your setting up a one to many relationship and it is not needed.  The `@JoinTable` annotation is primarily used for mapping many to many relationships, a scenario you do not need to account for.  Instead of `@JoinTable` use `@JoinColumn` to map this one to many relationship.

```
class TimeTable{
....
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "TIME_TABLE_ID"); 
private Set<Year> years;
...
}
```

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/JoinColumn

Answer (score 0):

ID corresponds to primary key in Year Entity